# Guardar datos de formularios diámicos con php en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Espero puedan ayudarme...
Sucede que hace varios dias trato de ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    include '../conec.php';
    $name_trab =$_POST['txt_nombre_trab'];
    $f_ini_1 =$_POST['txt_f_inicio'];
    $f_fin_1 =$_POST['txt_f_fin'];
    $hrs_hombre =$_POST['txt_hrs_hombre'];
    foreach($name_trab as $key => $nt){
        $cosulta10 = mysql_query ("SELECT e.empleado_id, empleado_nombre, sueldo FROM empleados AS e, puesto AS p, area AS a, `sql` AS s WHERE p.area_id = a.area_id AND p.puesto_id = e.puesto_id AND a.area_id =2 AND e.empleado_id = s.codigo AND empleado_nombre='".$nt."'");
        $cotador=count($name_trab);
        $id_empleado=array();
        $sueldo=array();
        $nombre=array();
        while($i=mysql_fetch_array($cosulta10)){
            $id_empleado[]=$i[0];
            $sueldo[]=$i[2];
            $nombre[]=$i[1];
        }
        for($i=0;$i<=$cotador;$i++){
            $id_empleado[$i];
            $sueldo[$i];
            $nombre[$i];
        }
    }
    include "../conexion.php";
    $solic_num =$_POST['num_solicitud'];
    $fecha_ini =$_POST['txt_f_inicio_s1'];
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
    $fecha_fin =$_POST['txt_f_termino_s1'];
    $tipo_ss =$_POST['tipo_servic'];
    $trab_realiz =$_POST['act_realizadas'];
    $consulta=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `costos_trabajos` VALUES (NULL, '".$solic_num."', '".$fecha_db_ini."', '".$fecha_db_fin."', '".$trab_realiz."', NULL)") or die ("<h2> Error de envio</h2>");
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
    $cotadorr=$cotador-1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$cotadorr;$i++)
    {
        $consulta2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `mano_obra` (`id_Mano_Obra`, `id_Trabajo`, `id_Trabajador`, `trabajador`, `f_Inicio`, `f_Termino`, `horas`, `costo`) VALUES
(NULL, '".$id."', '".$id_empleado[$i]."', '".$nombre[$i]."', '".$f_ini_1[$i]."', '".$f_fin_1[$i]."', '".$hrs_hombre[$i]."', NULL);");
         $sueldo_hora=$sueldo[$i]/8;
         $mostrar_datos=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mano_obra WHERE id_Trabajo=".$id." AND id_Trabajador='".$id_empleado[$i]."' ");
         while($x=mysql_fetch_array($mostrar_datos))
         {
             $total_costo=$x[6]*$sueldo_hora;
             $cambiar_costo=mysql_query("UPDATE mano_obra SET costo = '". $total_costo."' WHERE id_Mano_Obra = $x[0]");
         }
    }
?>
```

El detalle surge al momento de guardar los datos en la DB, ya que si agrego 2 o mas inputs (creados dinámicamente, por medio de un botón) en mi DB solo se guarda el último valor que se ingresa a los inputs y no gaurda los anteriores. (Para los inputs $name_trab, $f_ini_1, $f_fin_1, $hrs_hombre. Dichos inputs son una fila de una tabla)
Espero alguien me pueda ayudar...

Comment: Parece que el problema está en que no mandas todos los nombres que necesitas, por lo que necesitariamos ver cómo mandas los datos a este php para poder ayudartre

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia el codigo html se asemeja al codigo que muestran aqui abajo como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En el código HTML, dentro del `<form>`, a cada campo que quieres enviar varias veces le tienes que añadir `[]`:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <!-- linea 1 -->
    Nombre: <input name="nombre[]">
    Fecha de inicio: <input name="inicio[]">
    Fecha de fin: <input name="fin[]">

    <!-- linea 2 -->
    Nombre: <input name="nombre[]">
    Fecha de inicio: <input name="inicio[]">
    Fecha de fin: <input name="fin[]">

    <input type="submit>"
</form>
```

De esta forma, en el PHP, podrás leer los datos así:

```
$array_nombres = $_POST['nombre'];
$array_fechas_inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
$array_fechas_fin = $_POST['fin'];
```

Y necesitarás iterar cada array (que deberían tener el mismo número de elementos) para sacar los datos de cada persona:

```
foreach($array_nombres as $idx => $nombre) {
    $inicio = $array_fechas_inicio[$idx];
    $fin = $array_fechas_fin[$idx];
    // haz lo que quieras ahora con $nombre, $inicio y $fin
}
```

Comment: tal y como muestas este codigo se asemeja al que tengo, de la misma manera en que tienes el HTML asi lo tengo

Comment: Perdona, en ese caso no sé dónde puede estar el problema.

Comment: Según yo...
el problema esta en...
`$cotadorr=$cotador-1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$cotadorr;$i++)`